# Memory stream is not expandable even when incapsulated in using()

Tags: c#

I am using multiple memory streams to convert my file names to stream and write in them like so:

```
public static void Save() {
    try {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Clients.txt"))) {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms)) {
                writeClients(sw);
            } */ Line 91 */
        }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hotels.txt"))) {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms)) {
                writeHotels(sw);
            }
        } 
        [...]
    } catch {
        [...]
    }
}
```

but somehow when I call `Save()` I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Memory stream is not expandable.
   at System.IO.__Error.MemoryStreamNotExpandable()
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
   at csharp.Program.Save() in /home/nids/Documents/csharp/Program.cs:line 91
   at csharp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/nids/Documents/csharp/Program.cs:line 290
```

Where line 290 is the line where I call `Save()`

I'm not sure what's causing the error!

Comment: Look at line 91.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Line 91 is the 6th line in the code I posted which is the bracket that closes using of the StreamWriter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a memory stream that reads from the utf8 representation of the **string** `Clients.txt`, not from a file.

Memory streams that wrap a fixed byte array are non-resizable so you can't write more than the size of the byte array you initialise them with.

If your intention was to write to a file, refer to [How to Write to a file using StreamWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021125/how-to-write-in-file-using-streamwriter)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a `MemoryStream` over a `pre-allocated` byte array, it can't expand (ie. get longer than the size you specified when you started)

```
var length =Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Clients.txt");
  //    the length here is 11 bytes
```

you are pre-allocating a `buffer of 11` bytes and not the length of the file so when you  try to read a string upper than 11 bytes you will get an error

if you need to get the length of the file you should use `FileInfo.Length`