# Ziparchive append to exists file

Tags: c#

How to write (append) data to an existing file before?

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
   {
       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> file in files)
       {
          ZipArchiveEntry orderEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Key, CompressionLevel.Optimal); //create a file with this name
          var writer = new BinaryWriter(orderEntry.Open());
          writer.Write(file.Value); //write the binary data
       }
   }
   return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

---

First: `Data.Add("Filename.txt", byteArray());`
Two: `Data.Add("Filename.txt", byteArray());`

All data should be written to one file, and it creates a copy

Comment: Shouldn't `ZipArchiveMode.Create` be `ZipArchiveMode.Update`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53695616/4800344

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, At the output, an empty archive is obtained with this method.

Comment: Can't you modify the file all in once and then add it in one go?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I use `Dictionary`, file data and file name add to dictionary.
Then I use the recording of all data to the archive once.
But the result is different.

Comment: You are clearly missing a using block, `using(writer = new BinaryWriter(orderEntry.Open()))`... but I can't understand what you goal is. Do you want to append alle the byte-arrays in your dictionary values into a single file in the ZipArchive? Try rewording a bit ;)

Comment: @Steeeve, I want to add additional text to the previous one in the file to which the text was already added earlier, after that I want to write one more text to the same file (overwrite the file) (Sorry for my English)

Comment: You can't directly append to an existing ZipArchiveEntry. Try extracting it first to a MemoryStream, append the additional content from your dictionary to that MemoryStream and recreate the entry from the MemoryStream.

Comment: I would be grateful for the code